# Shoulder muscle problem

Tags: diet, muscle, shoulders

I got my right shoulder tear while doing a Bicep Preacher exercise. I have been off from the gym since February. I have pain only during motion, but after two months, I think I have the same intensity of pain. Can anybody guide me on how long it takes for healing? I don't have any swelling or bleeding, but the pain is, I think, the same since from that first day.

I consulted with an orthopedist. He told me to leave off on the gym for two weeks, but it's been almost two months that I have not gone to the gym. Is there anything I can add to my diet to improve my healing?

Comment: We cannot diagnose you over the Internet. Please see a qualified doctor.

Comment: @alec where does he ask for a diagnosis ?

Comment: @james - "can any body guide me how long does it take for healing" - Well, to know this, we'd have to know what the source of the pain is, and figuring that out is called diagnosing.

Comment: You lack consistency in your flagging/voting and decision making Alec. He hasn't asked for a diagnosis, he's also asked about diet. His questions are legitimate. Try to be helpful to people rather than a hinderance

Comment: @James Alec is correct in this case. "Diagnose" in this case is a medically-slanted term for "root-cause". To ensure a question is answered correctly, the root-cause of a problem should be determined; Alec says (correctly) this is not possible or advisable over the internet. Questions on the topic of nutrition that are not directly about exercises are off topic as well.

Comment: I'm a little confused,  there are many topics discussing diet for repairing muscle, mostly timing of protein etc  these don't seem to be off topic, yet diets to help with shoulder muscle repair are ?

Comment: Repair in the context of "recovery" is fine as it is specifically about how nutrition can aid development of physical fitness through faster normal recovery (IIRC). Repair in the context of injury is not.

Comment: @james - You have been a member of the site for about 10 days. I would suggest that before you start berating members for inconsistency, you take a little more time to understand the site and what is/is not considered on topic.